# Linux - archived view of folders (and files) without actual disk occupation - how?

Tags: linux, backup, archiving

System: 
Linux Mint 16 with Xfce.

Context: 
For remote backup I use encfs with the reverse option (http://linux.die.net/man/1/encfs). This gives me an encrypted view of files on disk. I can then rsync this encrypted view to another computer. The remote host contains the encrypted versions of the files on the original computer, without the need of having the encrypted version physically on disk on the original computer.

Question: 
I'd like to achieve the same thing but instead of encrypting, I'd like to have an archived view. So is there a way to have an 'archived' view of a folder (and its content) without actually creating an archive on disk? I would then copy the archived view.

I'm open for any other suggestions that achieve the same thing: having an archived view that I can copy without the need to have physical disk space occupied.

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

What's an archived view? A tar archive? You can pipe the output of tar to ssh:

`tar -c <directory> | ssh user@host "cat > /path/to/remote/filename.tar"`

and pipe through gzip if you want it compressed:

`tar -c <directory> | gzip | ssh user@host "cat > /path/to/remote/filename.tar.gz"`

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. Two questions: 1) If the underlying content does not change, will this result in an identical archive for each "tar ..." execution?
2) I partially use Crashplan where I need to configure the folders to backup. The reverse encfs approach from the original question gives me a "folder" that I can select. Is there a way by using your pipe approach to achieve something similar?